# Is there a website that links words in the Bible to relevant wikipedia articles?

Tags: bible

I'm looking for something like Strong's Concordance but for historical cities and other things that the average modern Westerner wouldn't understand without research. I'm reading Isaiah 15 and there are several place names (Ar, Kir, Dibon, Nebo, Medeba, etc) that are completely unfamiliar to me but some quick searches on wikipedia told me all I was looking for. I would like a (free) bible study tool that links to those kinds of things with footnotes or something. Doesn't have to be wikipedia but that was my first thought.

[Strong's Concordance](https://strongsconcordance.org/results.html?k=dibon) shows all occurrences of Dibon and says

> or (shortened) Diybon {dee-bone'}; from 01727; pining:--Dibon, the name of three places in Palestine:--Dibon. (Also, with 01410 added, Dibon-gad.)

But what I wanted to know is exactly what [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhiban,_Jordan#Dhiban_and_the_Israelites) says

> According to the Bible, the Israelites stopped at Dhiban during the Exodus. The Bible mentions "Divon" (Hebrew: דִּיבֹן), or "Divon Gad" (דִּיבֹן גָּד‎) because the city was said to have been occupied by the tribe of Gad. The name in Biblical Hebrew means wasting or pining.

> According to the Mesha Stele found at the site, Mesha, a Moabite king from the 9th century BCE, expelled the Israelites and established ancient Dhiban as an important settlement in the kingdom of Moab.

Comment: There's books like Harper's Bible Dictionary, which might be better (i.e. more reliable) than Wikipedia.

Comment: Read the Bible. Keep Wikipedia open in your browser. When you see a word you want to look up, type it into the search box of Wikipedia.

Comment: @DJClayworth thanks for the response but that's not helpful. I'm already aware of that. I'm interested in an integrated study environment

Comment: Tecarta 8 has a 'Define' feature which lets you open a definition google search in response to an extended press on any word. Not sure about new Tecarta. It's not surprising that most reputable Bible publishers steer well clear of wikipedia, so your use case is a bit niche due to being so apecific, and you may need to search manually.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant It doesn't necessarily have to be Wikipedia, but linking to Wikipedia would probably be less complicated since it's a free resource. Thanks for mentioning Tecarta, I'm checking it out now!